# java Jackson Mapper - nested properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have 2 simple entities

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public User owner;
}
```

Jackson can successfully deserialize this json.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "theItem",
    "owner": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "theUser"
    }
}
```

`new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON, Item.class);`

**The Problem**

I would like to know if it is possible to deserialize next json without having to create another entity (Item2.class).

I would like to deserialize it using Item.class

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "theItem",
      "owner_id": 2,
      "owner_name": "theUser"
  }



  public class Item2 {
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public int owner_id;
        public String owner_name;
    }
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: What do you mean by `I would like to know if it is possible to deserialize next json without having to create another entity`?

Comment: If I well understand, you would like to map a json object to Item class, right? If yes, I think there is no problem. In spite of nested properties, there is no LOOP properties in Json.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex I wouldn't want to have to create Item2.class

Comment: What you are doing looks like it came _directly_ from "[Getting Started with Custom Deserialization in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)" ... so isn't a Custom Deserializer what you'd want?

Comment: A method to do this is described here [Mapping Nested Values with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it but just creating `Map<String,Object>` Jackson takes care of converting value to Integers or String,  below is the code that works

```
public class Item {

public int id;
public String name;
public Map<String, Object> owner ;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Map<String, Object> getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
public void setOwner(Map<String, Object> owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying to _get rid of_ `class User` and use a Map instead?

Comment: sorry, yes get rid of `User` and use `Map`